# Tweet Button to tweet URL without http://www

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to embed a tweet button in my page that tweets a dynamically generated url.

I've gotten the button to tweet the full url, but in the interest of minimizing characters in the tweet, I'd like to strip out the `http://www`. However, when I attempt assign this to the data-url attribute of the twitter button anchor tag, the url does not appear in the tweet.

Thus, `$url = 'http://www.mypage.com/?id=2'` works `$url = 'mypage.com/?id=2'` does not.

I'm using the js api and my implementation is as follows:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" data-url="<?php echo $url;?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="test copy" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
```

plus twitter's js:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I can see why http stuff would be necessary to broaden the url scope, but in the interest of serving their main customer base, I would think twitter might have a way of making this info implicit. Is there something I can add that tells twitter, 'interpret this as http://www.blahblahblah...'?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$url = '//mypage.com/?id=2'`. It's called a protocol-relative URL. Might work.

Comment: Thanks man- unfortunately it looks like twitter adds the 'http://www' when I do this

Answer (score 1):

Setting the`data-url=" "`
and `data-text= <my url>` works fine, and apparently twitter knows to make urls in data-text into anchor tags. Not technically an answer but functionally the same as far as I can tell